# Counting page views in flask with google analytics

Tags: python, flask, google-analytics

I am creating a video streaming app for university project. I want to count number of views specific video has. The question is, is it a good idea to do that using google analytics. or should I just store video stats in some kind of a database.

Answer (score 0):

You could do both. Google analytics would require the least amount of work on your part since you simply cut and paste the code they give you on every page which needs tracking.

You could also do your own tracking as part of the python function which implements some [flask view](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/views/). Whenever the view corresponding to a video page gets called, you could increment a counter in a database or, even easier, write the video id out to a file and post-process the data later if that's easier.